# What does "cell" stands for in IDRISI?

Tags: terrset

Is "cell" in IDRISI (for ex. in area calculation) the same thing as pixel? Or what else it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cell stands for pixel, not only in IDRISI but in any raster data. You can check [What is raster data?](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=What_is_raster_data%3F), although this is expained in ArcGIS, but it applies in raster data in general.